# Putting a list into a SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a `List<Contact>` and I'ld like to put it into a SQLite database.

I've read some other posts saying you need to convert the List to a JSONArray and store it as a TEXT field in the array but I'm a beginner and this is all very confusing.

So far I have a method as follows:

```
public JSONArray void toJSON() {
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myList);
return jsonArray
}
```

Then in my sqlite database I say:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CONTACTS, group.toJSON());
```

But I am getting an error saying *The method put(String, String) in the type ContentValues is not applicable for the arguments (String, JSONArray)*. I dont know how to properly get it to a string though. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can call `JSONArray#toString()` to get a `String` representation of the JSON array. However, storing a list of contacts as a JSON array in a row of a DB seems a little fishy...

Comment: Why not just loop through that list of Contact objects and insert them via contentValues to your database?

Comment: @Matthew yeah I agree with you but I cant think of any other way. I had an idea that maybe, instead of each group having a list of contacts, each contact can have a string field that says what group theyre in. The only drawback to that is, I wont be able to have a contact in multiple groups because then i'd need a string array to store in the contacts database. Which is pretty much the same as storing a List<Contacts> in the groups database. This is a pickle.

Comment: @Razgriz can you give me some example code? Im not really sure what you mean.

Comment: @Clay Is the Contact class something that can be mapped to a database schema? If so, you can have a Contact table that has columns for the different contact fields such as name, email, etc and store your contacts there.

Comment: Someone skipped a bunch of fundamentals. You should be storing the values of the Contact object, not a JSON representation of it. Read the docs, especially http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html.

Comment: @Matthew Yeah I have a fully working ContactsDatabase. Im trying to implement a Groups feature where I can add contacts to a group. But I need to store my groups in a database so android remembers them. And each group has a list of contacts thats why I need to be able to add them to the groups database. So far my groups database is only recording the groups name, so when I get a group from the database, it doesnt have any contacts.

Comment: @PaulBurke Yeah but there are multiple contacts that each group have. So instead of storing a list of Contact objects - i'd have to store a list of contact names, contact numbers, contact addresses etc etc which is harder isnt it?

Comment: @Clay Might be a good idea to instead create a foreign key referencing Group IDs for each Contact in the Contacts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is one sample code, hope it could help u.

```
class Contact {
    public int id,
    public String name;
    public String phone;
}
class ContactColumns {
    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String PHONE = "phone";
}
private List<ContentValues> buildContentValueList(String jsonStr) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(jsonStr)) {
        return null;
    }
    List<ContentValues> list = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
    for (i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jb = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
        if (jb == null) {
            continue;
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactColumns.ID, jb.optInt("ID_KEY"));
        values.put(ContactColumns.NAME, jb.optString("NAME_KEY"));
        values.put(ContactColumns.PHONE, jb.optString("PHONE_KEY"));
        list.add(contact);
    }
    return list;
}

public void insertContact(List<ContentValues> valueList) {
    if (valueList.size() > 0) {
        ContentValues[] valueArray = new ContentValues[valueList.size()];
        valueArray = valueList.toArray(valueArray);
        getContentResolver().bulkInsert(ContactTable.URI, valueArray);
    }
}

you can call insertContact(buildContentValueList(jsonString)) to complete, that's all.
```